# Putty session opened from .bat file executes commands before login

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, batch-file, putty

So, I have been trying to login to PuTTy through a .bat file and run a command from a file. But it seems to execute the commands before the authentication is done.
My .bat file is like this

start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\PuTTY\putty.exe -ssh server_name -l usr_name -pw password -m commands_sbl.txt -t

FYI - The authentication takes a couple of seconds[around 2secs].

Comment: Explain your error or whatever is indicating the issue with more clarity if you can.

Comment: If that really happens, it's a bug of the server, not PuTTY. So you have to tell us more about the server.